# How to mesure React Native performance in production

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, performance

I want to find tools and technics about how to measure JS thread performance problems in production. I know how to do it in dev mode, for example, I can detect rerenders with https://github.com/welldone-software/why-did-you-render or use Flipper and React Dev tools. However, in production, we can come across slow devices and functionality which works fine on developer's phones or emulators can be slow.

How do you do with it? Maybe we can use something from the native world for IOS and Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an interesting solution - [react-native-performance](https://shopify.github.io/react-native-performance/)

It allows measuring:

- App startup render time
- Navigation render time
- Screen re-render time

and send this data to analytics systems https://shopify.github.io/react-native-performance/docs/reporting
Also, it is possible to turn on/off it with feature flag.